# How to detect ALT key press regardless focus in C++ Win32 application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Am I correct, that the only way to detect an <kbd>ALT</kbd> key press in a C++ Windows application is the keyboard hook?

Could be multiple child windows and setting `WM_KEYDOWN` for each of them is not an option.

Accelerator `"VK_MENU, some_id, VIRTKEY"` doesn't seem to work.

There is no main menu to steal `ALT` functionality. Plain Win32, no MFC.

Comment: If you own the application you don't need hooks

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What *problem* are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: I own the skeleton of the application, but it may have inplace activeX controls. @IInspectable: I am trying to capture Alt key press to generate message to main window. For example, to generate main menu.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: WM_KEY* is sent to the window, which has focus. If focus is on embedded activeX, main window doesn't have it.

Comment: Guys, instead of downgrading the question, please suggest a solution - if it exists - thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I am well aware of WM_KEY* queues, but it does not apply. Just to make sure, I tested, no worky.

Comment: @AndreiKalantarian If you don't own the window that receives the key strokes, and can't subclass the window, then yes, you would need a keyboard/message hook instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau; thanks. No silver bullet :(

Comment: Just curious, why the question was downgraded. I already noted, that "WM_KEYDOWN is not an option". It looks like, that if somebody cannot answer, he downgraded the question.

Comment: As Remy said, you may need a keyboard hook, why doesn't this solve your problem?

Comment: Have you tried using IOleControlSite::TranslateAccelerator to listen to keyboard messages delivered to the ActiveX controls? There is already mechanism for the ActiveX host and control to negotiate keyboard messages and menus. After all, Excel and Internet Explorer manage to do it.

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT: it does, but accelerator would be much nicer option. Looks like, it doesn't work for Alt, even when there is no menu. I posted a question, hoping, that I am missing something.

Comment: @RaymondChen: weird, but neither of the methods OleInplaceFrame::TranslateAccelerstor or DocHostUIHandler::TranslateAccelerator is called when I press any key with focus on WebBrowser activeX.. Most probably, I need to set a flag elsewhere. Will try to find out. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
    if (msg.message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN && msg.wParam == VK_MENU) {
        // single ALT key pressed, do something
    }
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: That only works if the window actually receives a message. Not guaranteed if the window is not in the foreground.

Comment: @selbie: yes, that is exactly what I needed. Same as accelerator. I would rather add it to accelerators table, but looks like it doesn't support "SYSKEY*" messages.

Comment: This would necessitate that the system always executes your message loop. As it turns out, this is not the case. The system will spin up its own nested message loop bypassing yours. This can happen for a number of reasons, e.g. when moving/resizing a window, when opening a menu, or when displaying a modal dialog.

Comment: @IInspectable: the goal is to make it act like accelerator, so it is OK with dialogs or when any other process is currently active. But you are correct about resizing a window: in one specific weird scenario process loses activation and I have to push the button twice unless I click anywhere on the window. Theoretically it is still OK (accelerators acts same way). This is easy to compensate.